# ER-Diagram with mc-Syntax, name of inventor?

Tags: entity-relationship

SQL ER-Diagram. I know the Chen-Syntax, UML-Syntax and Martin-Syntax. Sometimes I use the mc-Syntax: c is 1 or nothing, m are multiple.
Who is the Inventor of the mc ER-Diagram Syntax?

Comment: Unrelated, but: an ER diagram has nothing to do with SQL

Comment: To be more specific. I create with SQL a database schema. Then I create an entity-relationship model (ER-Model not ER-Diagram) for documentation, with a tool (Reverse-Engineering). Now, I find out (Wikipedia), that **Peter Chen** has created the Chen – Syntax (cardinalities between quantities), also known as **mc-syntax**.